# Dump SQL to file: data with accent (italian) different charset

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I'm using a procedure to dump a database content and write a file sql...

Everything works but in my file all data which have specific chars (like è, à ù é ç etc,...) get lost in the file...I'm a little confused now. ... where I have to set the right charset?

My database got a default charset UTF8 and Collation UTF8_general_ci

Data are handled correctly from the DB in my server side script (CRUD works correcly and data is displayed correctly). When I get my data in variable and I write down the completely SQL procedure to a file, accented letters get corrupted...

This is my dumping procedure which returns a complete dump of my db

========================================================================

function dumpDatabase() {

```
        // Connect to database
    $db = mysql_select_db($this->DATABASE_DB);

    if (!$db) {
        die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
    }
    if (!empty($db)) {


        // Get all table names from database
        $c = 0;
        $result = mysql_list_tables($this->DATABASE_DB);
        for($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($result); $x++) {
            $table = mysql_tablename($result, $x);
            if (!empty($table)) {
                $arr_tables[$c] = mysql_tablename($result, $x);
                $c++;
            }
        }


            // Structure Header
            $structure .= "-- \n";
            $structure .= "-- Backup effettuato il `".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."` \n";
            $structure .= "-- Backup per database `{$this->DATABASE_DB}` \n";               
            $structure .= "-- \n\n";

            $structure .= "-- \n\n";
            $structure .= "-- \n\n";

            $structure .= "SET NAMES utf8; \n";
            $structure .= "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;";


            $structure .= "-- \n\n";
            $structure .= "-- \n\n";

        // List tables
        $dump = '';
        for ($y = 0; $y < count($arr_tables); $y++){

            // DB Table name
            $table = $arr_tables[$y];

            // Structure Header
            $structure .= "-- \n";
            $structure .= "-- Table structure for table `{$table}` \n";
            $structure .= "-- \n\n";

            // Dump Structure
            $structure .= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$table}`; \n";
            $structure .= "CREATE TABLE `{$table}` (\n";
            $result = mysql_db_query($this->DATABASE_DB, "SHOW FIELDS FROM `{$table}`");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

                $structure .= "  `{$row->Field}` {$row->Type}";
                $structure .= (!empty($row->Default)) ? " DEFAULT `{$row->Default}`" : false;
                $structure .= ($row->Null != "YES") ? " NOT NULL" : false;
                $structure .= (!empty($row->Extra)) ? strtoupper(" {$row->Extra}") : false;
                $structure .= ",\n";

            }

            $structure = ereg_replace(",\n$", "", $structure);

            // Save all Column Indexes in array
            unset($index);
            $result = mysql_db_query($this->DATABASE_DB, "SHOW KEYS FROM `{$table}`");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

                if (($row->Key_name == 'PRIMARY') AND ($row->Index_type == 'BTREE')) {
                    $index['PRIMARY'][$row->Key_name] = $row->Column_name;
                }

                if (($row->Key_name != 'PRIMARY') AND ($row->Non_unique == '0') AND ($row->Index_type == 'BTREE')) {
                    $index['UNIQUE'][$row->Key_name] = $row->Column_name;
                }

                if (($row->Key_name != 'PRIMARY') AND ($row->Non_unique == '1') AND ($row->Index_type == 'BTREE')) {
                    $index['INDEX'][$row->Key_name] = $row->Column_name;
                }

                if (($row->Key_name != 'PRIMARY') AND ($row->Non_unique == '1') AND ($row->Index_type == 'FULLTEXT')) {
                    $index['FULLTEXT'][$row->Key_name] = $row->Column_name;
                }

            }

            // Return all Column Indexes of array
            if (is_array($index)) {
                foreach ($index as $xy => $columns) {

                    $structure .= ",\n";

                    $c = 0;
                    foreach ($columns as $column_key => $column_name) {

                        $c++;

                        $structure .= ($xy == "PRIMARY") ? "  PRIMARY KEY  (`{$column_name}`)" : false;
                        $structure .= ($xy == "UNIQUE") ? "  UNIQUE KEY `{$column_key}` (`{$column_name}`)" : false;
                        $structure .= ($xy == "INDEX") ? "  KEY `{$column_key}` (`{$column_name}`)" : false;
                        $structure .= ($xy == "FULLTEXT") ? "  FULLTEXT `{$column_key}` (`{$column_name}`)" : false;

                        $structure .= ($c < (count($index[$xy]))) ? ",\n" : false;

                    }

                }

            }

            $structure .= "\n);\n\n";

            // Header
            $structure .= "-- \n";
            $structure .= "-- Dumping data for table `$table` \n";
            $structure .= "-- \n\n";

            // Dump data
            unset($data);


            //mysql_set_charset('latin1');
            $result     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
            $num_rows   = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {

                $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
                $data .= "INSERT INTO `$table` (";

                // Field names
                for ($x = 0; $x < $num_fields; $x++) {

                    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $x);

                    $data .= "`{$field_name}`";
                    $data .= ($x < ($num_fields - 1)) ? ", " : false;

                }

                $data .= ") VALUES (";

                // Values
                for ($x = 0; $x < $num_fields; $x++) {
                    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $x);

                    $data .= "'" . str_replace('\"', '"', mysql_escape_string($row->$field_name)) . "'";
                    $data .= ($x < ($num_fields - 1)) ? ", " : false;

                }

                $data.= ");\n";
            }

            $data.= "\n";

            $dump .= $structure . $data;
            $dump .= "-- --------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

        }

        return $dump;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use mysqldump? See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code after `SET NAMES utf8;`  or use `mysqldump` utility.

```
SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8';
```

Comment: If using mysqldump, use parameter `--default-character-set=utf8`.